# Bootstrap trying to put an image on the container :after & :before

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to put an image on the right and left edges of the container's with the :before and :after.
But for some reason the containers totally .... up when I add a position absolute to the before and afters...

It has probably something to do with the standard bootstrap before and afters on the containers

Any idea how I can go around this?

```
.header,
.spotlight,
.main,
.footer {
  >.container {
    position: relative;
    &:before {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      background: url("../img/right.png");
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      width: 6px;
      right: -6px;
      z-index: 999999;
      top: 0;
    }
    &:after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      background: url("../img/left.png");
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      width: 6px;
      left: -6px;
      z-index: 999999;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

[Example how the shadow(image) should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzS6I.png)

Comment: can you not have a container for the container?

Comment: It would probably just add another before and after to the new container like the parent container

Comment: not if you don't use the bootstrap class - just use your own class and give it the same width

Comment: Thanks!  I've got it working :)